# TextView is not showing in customized view class in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I made a customized view extends RelativeLayout, I am trying to add text view (named nrText in the code below), the text view is not shown, I used `log.d` in my main fragment code (after adding MyView to the layout) to show the `MyView.getX()`and `MyView.getWidth()`, `getX()` is showing actual numbers, but `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` are showing zero.

Here is the view class code:

```
  package com.example.myapplication2.ViewModels;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MyView extends RelativeLayout{
    private TextView nrText;
    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        nrText.setLayoutParams(lp2);
        nrText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        nrText.setTextSize(70);
        nrText.setX(getWidth()/2f);
        nrText.setY(getHeight()/2f);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        removeView(nrText);
        addView(nrText);
    }

    private void init(Context context){
        nrText = new TextView(context);
    }
}
```

I tried changing this part

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
nrText.setLayoutParams(lp2);
```

by this part:

```
  nrText.setWidth(100);
  nrText.setHeight(100);
```

but nothing changed.

Here is my fragment code (note that I tries to set nrText width again but still returning zero.

```
public class Start4 extends Fragment {


    private MyView v;
 

        v.nrText.setWidth(100);

        v.nrText.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Log.d("sdad",String.valueOf(v.nrText.getX() + " " + v.nrText.getHeight()));
            }
        });    

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.st4, container, false);
        v=view.findViewById(R.id.ss);


        return view;
    }
}
```

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.myapplication2.ViewModels.MyView
    android:id="@+id/ss"
    tools:context=".StartModels.StartMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Logging results:

```
D/sdad: 540.0 0
D/sdad: 540.0 0
D/sdad: 540.0 0
D/sdad: 540.0 0
D/sdad: 540.0 0
D/sdad: 540.0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class MyView extends ViewGroup {
    private TextView nrText;
    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context){
        nrText = new TextView(context);
        LayoutParams lp2 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        nrText.setLayoutParams(lp2);
        nrText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        nrText.setTextSize(70);
        nrText.doOnLayout {
            nrText.setX(getWidth()/2f);
            nrText.setY(getHeight()/2f);
        }
        addView(nrText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I am using Java, I tried moving "nrText.setY(getHeight()/2f);" and "nrText.setLayoutParams(lp2);" to onLayout method but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

After two days of searching I got it, I didn't call `super.onLayout`, calling it solved the problem.